# Amazon Cognito + iOS Swift - Custom UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-ios

I'm trying to setup Amazon Cognito with a custom UI I've set up in Swift for iOS. The built-in UI from the Amazon iOS SDK doesn't fit the look of the app, so I can't use it.

Anyone here have advice on how to use Amazon Cognito with a custom UI?

[This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uNtrLZhs5k) shows me how to use Cognito, but NOT using a custom UI.

Answer (score 2):

There are two available AWS SDKs to satisfy this use-case:

- The AWS iOS SDK[a].
- The AWS Amplify iOS SDK[b].

For a sample app that you could use as a reference while writing code, you could also take a look at this iOS application[c], and build your own application with a custom UI while referring to the steps in the readme of the application. This Github repository has codes both in Objective C and Swift, which is another bonus.

## References

[a]. https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios

[b]. https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication

[c]. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample